# submit form when elements change

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, if I assign `class=auto_submit_form` to a form, it will be submitted whenever any element is changed, with the following code:

```
/* automatically submit if any element in the form changes */
$(function() {
  $(".auto_submit_form").change(function() {
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

However, if I want to the form to submit only when specified elements are changed:

```
/* submit if elements of class=auto_submit_item in the form changes */
$(function() {
  $(".auto_submit_item").change(function() {
    $(this).parents().filter("form").submit();
  });
});
```

I'm just learning jQuery. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: is this a special plug-in you're using, or is it some built-in functionality of jQuery I've never heard of?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 /* submit if elements of class=auto_submit_item in the form changes */
$(function() {
   $(".auto_submit_item").change(function() {
     $("form").submit();
   });
 });
```

Assumes you only have one form on the page.  If not, you'll need to do select the form that is an ancestor of the current element using `$(this).parents("form").submit()`

Comment: using "this.form.submit();" would be even better because you wouldn't have to instantiate the jQuery object.

Comment: @tvanfosson any tips how to prevent page refresh with this solution? `preventDefault()` and `return false` not working :(

Comment: @Toon this code causes the form to do a normal submit.  If you don't want a page refresh, then serialize the form and send it via AJAX instead.

    `var $form = $('form');
    var data = $form.serialize();
    $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(...);`

Answer (score 13):

You can use an expression in the `parents()` method to filter the parents. Hence this might be a little more efficient:

```
/* submit if elements of class=auto_submit_item in the form changes */
$(".auto_submit_item").change(function() {
    $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would give an id to the form:

```
$(".auto-submit-item").change(function() {
    $("form#auto-submit").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a generic approach to this:

```
$('.autoSubmit, .autoSubmit select, .autoSubmit input, .autoSubmit textarea').change(function () {
    const el = $(this);
    let form;

    if (el.is('form')) { form = el; }
    else { form = el.closest('form'); }

    form.submit();
});
```

All elements of a form:

```
<form class="autoSubmit">
    <select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
</form>
```

Only individual elements

```
<form>
    <select class="autoSubmit"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
</form>
```