# HTML/Razor: Post on Select change

Tags: html, forms, razor

Is it possible to trigger a form POST when changing a value of a select list WITHOUT using Javascript if possibe?

I'm using ASP.NET WebPages Razor but for the life of me cannot figure out how.
How would it be done with Javascript if Razor syntax cannot be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329805/submit-form-when-elements-change) shows how to do it with jQuery. I hope that gets you started. Also see [this blog post](http://jetlogs.org/2007/09/03/jquery-select-boxes-and-change-events/)